# Javascript counter, popup modal after hitting specific number

Tags: javascript

I currently have the below code, and I am wondering how I can make a popup modal appear after it hits like 200000, stopping the counter instead of just continuing to the 500000 number.

```
<div class="available-credits" id="value">500000</div>

function animateValue(obj, start = 0, end = null, duration = 600000) {
    if (obj) {
        var textStarting = obj.innerHTML;
        end = end || parseInt(textStarting.replace(/\D/g, ""));
        var range = end - start;
        var minTimer = 50;
        var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
        stepTime = Math.max(stepTime, minTimer);
        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        var endTime = startTime + duration;
        var timer;

        function run() {
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            var remaining = Math.max((endTime - now) / duration, 0);
            var value = Math.round(end - (remaining * range));
            obj.innerHTML = textStarting.replace(/([0-9]+)/g, value);
            if (value == end) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }

        timer = setInterval(run, stepTime);
        run();
    }
}

animateValue(document.getElementById('value'));
```

Comment: you should use `value >= end` instead of `==`, for these kind of guard condition. Not sure if it is solving your issue, though, it's just a comment for now.

Answer (score 0):

return is what you use to break out this kind of situations.
You can use some math to estimate the next iteration value and have this be more precise.

```
<div class="available-credits" id="value">500000</div>

function animateValue(obj, start = 0, end = null, duration = 600000, limit = 10000) {
    if (obj) {
        var textStarting = obj.innerHTML;
        end = end || parseInt(textStarting.replace(/\D/g, ""));
        var range = end - start;
        var minTimer = 50;
        var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
        stepTime = Math.max(stepTime, minTimer);
        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        var endTime = startTime + duration;
        var timer;

        function run() {
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            var remaining = Math.max((endTime - now) / duration, 0);
            var value = Math.round(end - (remaining * range));
            obj.innerHTML = textStarting.replace(/([0-9]+)/g, value);
            if(value >= limit)
            {
                    obj.innerHTML = limit;//cheat
                    clearInterval(timer);
                return;
            }
            if (value == end) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }

        timer = setInterval(run, stepTime);
        run();
    }
}

animateValue(document.getElementById('value'));
```

Comment: How does this help my problem, at all?

Comment: Man there's a limit in the function now, you did not even read it right? use it to trigger your modal. Good luck.